# Predict Name Origin with RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, text-classification

I'm trying to train a RNN to predict a names origin. The dataset is from a Pytorch tutorial, and I basically need to redo the tutorial using tensorflow/keras.

Dataset:

```
    !wget https://download.pytorch.org/tutorial/data.zip
    !unzip data.zip

    data = []
    for filename in glob('data/names/*.txt'):
      origin = filename.split('/')[-1].split('.txt')[0]
      names = open(filename).readlines()
      for name in names:
        data.append((name.strip(), origin))

    names, origins = zip(*data)
    names_train, names_test, origins_train, origins_test = train_test_split(names, origins, test_size=0.25, shuffle=True, random_state=123)

    for name, origin in zip(names_train[:20], origins_train[:20]):
      print(name.ljust(20), origin)

Bazhinov             Russian
Wasem                Arabic
Tumashev             Russian
Andreyanov           Russian
Dobrovolsky          Russian
Xie                  Chinese
Zhvykin              Russian
Belkov               Russian
Rahletzky            Russian
Jakuba               Russian
Kalinchuk            Russian
Jankin               Russian
Vanslov              Russian
Seif                 Arabic
Asghar               Arabic
Osladil              Czech
Brand                German
Findley              English
Cameron              English
Tsalikov             Russian
```

Data-Preprocessing:

```
encoder_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True)
encoder_train.fit_on_texts(names_train)

encoder_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True)
encoder_test.fit_on_texts(names_test)

sequences = encoder_train.texts_to_sequences(names_train)
sequences= tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences)

sequences_test= encoder_test.texts_to_sequences(names_test)
sequences_test= tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences_test)

encoder_org_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(lower=False)
encoder_org_train.fit_on_texts(origins_train)

encoder_org_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(lower=False)
encoder_org_test.fit_on_texts(origins_test)

origins_vec_train = encoder_org_train.texts_to_sequences(origins_train)
origins_vec_train = np.asarray(origins_vec_train)

origins_vec_test = encoder_org_test.texts_to_sequences(origins_test)
origins_vec_test = np.asarray(origins_vec_test)

embedding_input_dim = max(encoder_train.index_word) + 1
embedding_output_dim = 32
```

RNN Model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(layers=[
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=embedding_input_dim,
                            output_dim=embedding_output_dim,
                            mask_zero=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences= True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(19, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.075),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(sequences, origins_vec_train, epochs=10, batch_size= 200, validation_data= (sequences_test, origins_vec_test))
```

My model trains fine, and I get a better accuracy than I hoped for originally. Basically, what I am trying to do now, is create a function that takes a string input, and outputs an origin based on the network's training (i.e input = 'Sergey', output= 'Russian'). The function to do this in the Pytorch tutorial requires several other functions. I basically want to recreate this function:

```
def predict(input_line, n_predictions=3):
    print('\n> %s' % input_line)
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = evaluate(lineToTensor(input_line))

        # Get top N categories
        topv, topi = output.topk(n_predictions, 1, True)
        predictions = []

        for i in range(n_predictions):
            value = topv[0][i].item()
            category_index = topi[0][i].item()
            print('(%.2f) %s' % (value, all_categories[category_index]))
            predictions.append([value, all_categories[category_index]])
```

in the context of the Neural Network I created.

Comment: Be aware that you should apply softmax instead of sigmoid since you're doing multi-class classification.

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.predict` to generate predictions: [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict)

Also note that you're using different tokenisers for your training set and your test set. This will cause issues if for some reason your test set contains characters that were not present in the training set. You should use only one, that you fit only on training set, and use the `out of vocabulary` parameter `Tokenizer(char_level=True, oov_token='UNK')` for example.